# Sandbox not working. Error: Sorry to interrupt: force:showPanel

Tags: lightning, error, sandbox

I have a Sandbox environment which is constantly failing to work no matter what page I try and access (including Setup pages) and giving this error message in a popup:

> Sorry to interrupt
>   force:showPanel

[image]

And this message in the console:

> home:5 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   'nonce-null' chrome-extension: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
>   https://sfdc.azureedge.net *.visualforce.com
>   https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is
>   ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

Before I got stuck with the above message, I got this message:

[image]

It does not matter which page I try and load (Home, Setup, Account etc), I will always get the `Sorry to interrupt. force:showPanel` error.

Comment: The same as everyone else we are having the same issues today any updates from Salesforce?

Comment: I have the same issue in my sandbox. How can i do to resolve this issue in the meantime? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was caused by a bug in Salesforce and has now been fixed in our Sandbox.

Comment: Can you provide case number and bug number? It will help someone with same problem quoting it to SF support thus reaching solution faster.

Comment: Same problem here today. Did you do something special or just wait? :(

Comment: It hasn't been fixed in my org :(

Comment: @Raspi It was an issue in our sandbox org, and it passed after 48 hours.

Comment: @kabrice It was an issue in our sandbox org, and it passed after 48 hours.

Comment: Not fixed - we're still getting this one today, on go-live day!

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem this morning with our test sandbox.
The message was displayed after login with Lightning.
The problem was fixed (by Salesforce?) in the meantime and everything is working as expected.